# What compelled Benjamin Disraeli to label 1857 revolt as a "National Revolt"?

Tags: 19th-century, india, british-empire, revolution

It is still debated whether the [Indian Rebellion of 1857](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Rebellion_of_1857) in British India was  just a soldiers' mutiny or a National revolt for the independence.

But in July 1857, in House of Commons,  Benjamin Disraeli labeled it as a *national revolt.*

So, what compelled him to do so?

Answer (score 3):

There is an explanation [here](http://www.britishempire.co.uk/article/mutinypress.htm):

> In his speech Disraeli had contended that the incident involving the
>   greased cartridges had simply been the spark to the powder and that
>   the true causes of the rebellion, which he now referred to as a
>   national revolt, were a combination of interference by the British in
>   local land rights and property succession, the abolition of certain
>   religious customs, and the displacement of ancient royal houses. In
>   response The Saturday Review totally ridiculed the idea that there
>   could be any affection between the Sepoys and any of the deposed royal
>   families and used the fact that the Sepoys had sought out the employ
>   of a foreign power to dismiss the idea that there was any discontent
>   with the abolition of religious customs and land rights. In a later
>   article of the same date, The Saturday Review takes its anti Indian
>   royal families stand a step further in proclaiming that the only
>   mistake that had been made was in failing to dethrone all such
>   families and to totally take away any vestiges of power. In this was
>   they would not have been available to be used as rallying points for
>   the rebellious Sepoys.